# stat() and block size in Cygwin

Tags: filesystems, cygwin, stat

I want to have code similar to the function of `du`. I tried this by the use of `stat()` function. I have learned `st_blocks` reported from `stat()` is the actual block number allocated in disk. The block size should be 512 bytes and `st_blocks*512` should be the allocated byte number for the file. However I found confusing on Cygwin environment. First I create a file with 8KB using `dd` command.

```
% dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4096 count=2 of=testfile
2+0 records in
2+0 records out
8192 bytes (8.2 kB, 8.0 KiB) copied, 0.00791222 s, 1.0 MB/s
```

Then I run a `stat` command with the file:

```
% stat testfile
  File: testfile
  Size: 8192            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 7727c30h/124943408d     Inode: 25614222880771065  Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (197881/ crystal)   Gid: (  513/    None)
Access: 2018-05-01 15:11:50.760626400 +0800
Modify: 2018-05-01 15:11:50.761626500 +0800
Change: 2018-05-01 15:11:50.761626500 +0800
 Birth: 2018-05-01 15:11:50.760626400 +0800
```

I don't think there is a 'hole' on the generated file. I get the file with 8 blocks allocated, which implies the block size to be 1KiB rather than 512B. If I do C code with `stat()` call, `st_blocks` gets the same result.

So far all the articles say block size is 512B. Is there exception? If yes, how can I get the actual block size? Or, how can I get the actual disk space occupied  by a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stat` command line tool has a `%B` format option, which displays the block size it is using. It appears `stat` uses a 1024-byte block in Cygwin.

Also, it appears that the NTFS 4096-byte block size is actually what is being used under the hood, and `stat` is just presenting 1024-byte blocks:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo count=1 bs=4095
$ stat -c '%B %b' foo
1024 4
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=foo count=1 bs=4097
$ stat -c '%B %b' foo
1024 8
```

There is a discussion of where the 512-byte vs 1024-byte block sizes come from in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28780/file-block-size-difference-between-stat-and-ls. Apparently it is to do with Linux kernel conventions vs GNU utility conventions.

Comment: Thanks. Is there system call that could get block size as `stat %B`?

Comment: I don't think there is a system call - it isn't really a kernel thing. According to the Stack Exchange article, that size is set in a GNU lib header.